# Using multiple views in the same page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

Is it possible to use multiple view in the same SPA using AngularJS?

I am planning to use 1 view for the header-bar of the page, second one for the body of the page and the third one for the footer of the page. So that the header and footer view don't change every time the location is routed instead only change when depending on the action the user performs on the body, such as click on "Change header" button in the body view etc.

An example would really help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)** for this:

```
<div ng-include="'my-header.html'"></div>
<!-- body -->
<div ng-view></div>
<div ng-include="'my-footer.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, I found an example for this @ [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pARExi)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It's a well maintained community project that replace the basic ng-router.

It has a lot more functionalities than ng-router, including [multiple views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).